# Mysql replication between 3 + 1 nodes

Tags: mysql, galera

Suppose I have the following configuration for mysql 5.6 replication.
Nodes
A
B
C
D

Nodes A,B,C have wsrep_cluster_address set to respective ip's of nodes A,B and C. Then node D has wsrep_cluster_address set to respective ip's of nodes A,B,C and D.

Then when data is written to nodes A,B,C it is replicated to A,B,C,D, but when data write happens on D - it won't get replicated to A,B,C - is that right ?

Also, what happens when data is written on D and same record is changed on either A,B or C - does it get overwritten based on time of the actual change ?

Really the goal of D is just to have a constantly replicated copy in another zone in case a disaster happens.

Comment: For what it's worth MySql has come a long way in the features you want since 5.6 came out in 2013. If you're building something that complex why not upgrade?

Comment: Thats the plan, but the apps need to updated first for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have a cluster with nodes A,B,C, but not D.

Have D be a Slave to one of the nodes.  Do not configure it as a wsrep node.  Do not write to it.

**More**

A cluster with 3 or more nodes provides HA and failover if any one node goes down.

If those 3 nodes are in the same datacenter, then they are vulnerable to a disaster that takes down the DC.  (That *can* happen.)

If those 3 nodes are in 3 geographical locations, the cluster can survive the lost of any one of them.  Hence, it is better than 3 in a single DC.

When something happens with a cluster, all the alive nodes vote to see what the situation is.  If *more than 50%* can talk to each other, they will declare that they are the (degraded) cluster, and that the other node(s) will need repairing when (if) they reconnect.

If you have 3 nodes in one DC and a 4th in another DC, the cluster will *not* survive an outage of *either* DC.

If those two DCs lose connectivity, but everything other than the network stays up, the DC with 3 nodes won't be able to see the 4th; they will kick it out of the cluster.  The lone #4 will see that it can't get 50%+, so it stops accepting writes (at least).

Back to your question...

A 3-node cluster in one DC; a 4th node in another DC.  If the 3-node DC goes dark, you could *manually* build a new cluster around the 4th.  But that is far from automated.  You could, however, say that a DC going down (and not coming back up 'soon') is so rare that you are willing to build this topology.  And, if the DC never comes back up (tornado, flood, earthquake, tsunami), you would have a copy of the data in #4.  Better than nothing.

So, if you go with 3+1, I recommend that the 3 is a fully functioning Galera cluster.  (Or it could even be 2 live + 1 garbd.)  Then #4 would be an ordinary replica that is asynchronously replicating from one of the 3 nodes.

With that config, Galera does not know or care about #4, and is not burdened by long-distance syncing of gcache.

It's a tradeoff between vulnerability and speed.  You can't solve both.  Hopefully, I have given you enough understanding of what can be done so that you can decide what "keeps you up at night" the least.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer ? The reason why I thought ABC + D with wsrep was a good option was that in case zone with ABC went down then D could take incoming traffic and once it was back up it would sync up to D. But, by not having D in the wsrep config on ABC side - it would prohibit it from distributing any traffic to D. Essentially, I wanted to keep two sites with latest data and retain options for syncing once either of the site is back online with ABC site being the primary one. Does this make sense? My sites are 45ms apart round trip.

Comment: If you want that level of robustness, have two 3-node (or 2 full-node + 1 garbd) in each data center, plus bi-directional async replication between the two clusters.

Comment: I added more.  MariaDB has long included "Galera Cluster".  MySQL has recently (5.7 to some extent; 8.0 more so) provided "InnoDB Cluster".

Comment: RIck - cannot up vote your answer, but thank you. One more question - if you have two 3 node clusters in different zones. How do you setup replication between them in bi directional way. Do you make it a 6 node cluster altogether (but isn't 7 better in this case) ? Also, in case I was going to build 3 and replication to slave- what would be the fastest way to go back to 3 nodes after site with 3 nodes experiences outage and then I switch to site with backup node (is it dump, copy and restore at that point )?

Comment: @Cac3a - I have not heard of bidirectional, nor of writing to _both_ clusters.  Your 2-cluster idea sounds very similar to Primary-Primary, which has a number of problems.  There is nothing "bad" about an even number of nodes, only about having less than 3.

Comment: @Cac3a - I don't understand the rest of your Comment.  Perhaps you should start a new Question and spell out more details of your idea.  Be sure to tag [galera].